# split array for each checkbox with function declaration

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

im just asking if it is possible to alert the text inside array in each checkbox like if first **SOME TEXT** checked it will alert the first array and if the **second row was checked** it will alert the second array and so on and so forth

for example this is the HTML

```
<div id="inside">
  <label><input type="checkbox">SOME TEXT</label><br/>
  <label><input type="checkbox">SOME TEXT</label><br/>
  <label><input type="checkbox">SOME TEXT</label><br/>
  <label><input type="checkbox">SOME TEXT</label><br/>
  <label><input type="checkbox">SOME TEXT</label><br/>
  <label><input type="checkbox">SOME TEXT</label><br/>
  <label><input type="checkbox">SOME TEXT</label><br/>
</div>
```

and this is the **script**

```
jQuery(function(){
         var text = [
            "text 1",
            "text 2",
            "text 3",
            "text 4",
            "text 5",
            "text 6",
            "text 7"
        ];

        jQuery("input[type='checkbox']").click(function(){
          var y = jQuery(this).closest(label);
          jQuery(y).each(function(){
              if(jQuery(this).is(":checked")){

                 display(text) //function called

              }
           });
        });
    });
```

and this the **called function**

```
function display(x){
        var dis = "";
        for(var i = 0; i< x.length; i++){
            dis += alert(x[i]);
        }
        return dis;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the index of the checked checkbox, then alert/log the item in the same index.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var text = [
    "text 1",
    "text 2",
    "text 3",
    "text 4",
    "text 5",
    "text 6",
    "text 7"
  ];

  var $checks = $("input[type='checkbox']").click(function() {
    var idx = $checks.index(this);
    display(text[idx]);
  });
});


function display(x) {
  console.log(x);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="inside">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox">SOME TEXT</label>
  <br/>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox">SOME TEXT</label>
  <br/>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox">SOME TEXT</label>
  <br/>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox">SOME TEXT</label>
  <br/>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox">SOME TEXT</label>
  <br/>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox">SOME TEXT</label>
  <br/>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox">SOME TEXT</label>
  <br/>
</div>
```